# Linux: Listing all local and SAN disks on a host

Tags: linux, storage

I am attempting to list and categorize all connected disks on a host; local and SAN-connected. The SAN use various types of adapters (namely Emulex and Qlogic) so scanning the FC bus can be somewhat unreliable (some hosts use both types for whatever reason). Basically I am gathering data for various reporting and analytics.

My question is this: if I use 'blkid' to list local disks, and 'lsscsi' to list the SAN devices attached via fibrechannel, will that encompass all of the disks connected to the host?

I've not had a lot of experience with either command to know the in's and out's of them, so I wanted to see if their results are reliable enough to build a data framework.

I should note that this is a heavily scrutinized environment and extraneous tools will not be permitted to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably just compare `fdisk -l` and `lsscsi`.

On my systems, I tend to see more output in `fdisk`, as lsscsi doesn't account for all of the block devices in use on the servers (ZFS zpool devices, etc.) Similar situation for `blkid`.

Comment: Well @ewwhite, thanks for the response. The issue I have with fdisk -l is that it shows every path to a SAN device (we have 4 paths per lun), so it doesn't give me an accurate list of devices without paring through powerpath (or multipath) and truing up the paths with the device.

So far though, it looks like the contents of /sys/block will eventually be what I need, once I pair out the extra paths there, and the other non-disk stuff like ram and Vx paths.